# Run Python Script within Python & check if value is outputted - If statement

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, if-statement, boto3, amazon-iam

I have a Python3 script which basically runs through a list of Amazon AWS Account numbers (Uses Boto3), checks to see if their access keys are older than x number of days and report on it.

I'd like to make my report nice by checking to see if the output has a user(s) or not and output this into a file for SNS to email to me.

Here is the code I've already tried:

```
if not os.system("python3 ListUsersWithAccessKeysOlderThan90Days.py " + accountNumber):
            print("No Content", file=reportName)
        else:
            print("Content", file=reportName)
```

I've already tried this too:

```
        if os.system("python3 ListUsersWithAccessKeysOlderThan90Days.py " + accountNumber) == " ":
            print("No Content", file=reportName)
        else:
            print("Content", file=reportName)
```

But I only seem to get this in my output file:

```
Running on account accountNumber - accountLabel - accountEnvironment
No Content

Running on account accountNumber - accountLabel - accountEnvironment
No Content

Running on account accountNumber - accountLabel - accountEnvironment
No Content
```

Ideally, I'd like it to look like this:

```
Running on account accountNumber - accountLabel - accountEnvironment
No Content

Running on account accountNumber - accountLabel - accountEnvironment
Content

Running on account accountNumber - accountLabel - accountEnvironment
No Content
```

No Content = No access keys need rotating. 
Content = User needs their key rotating.

I can achieve this in Bash, but I wouldn't mind trying to get it working in Python3.

Here is my Bash example:

```
if [[ -z "$(python3 ListUsersWithAccessKeysOlderThan90Days.py ${ACCOUNT})" ]]; then
        echo -e "$ACCOUNT ($LABEL) is up to date no need to report\n" >> $REPORT
    else
    echo -e "$ACCOUNT Need keys rotating" >> $REPORT 
    fi
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: your actual output and your "ideally" are the same... Anyway, you can use `subprocess` to run scripts and get the output

Comment: I can't see any relation with aws, boto3 and so on.

Comment: What I'm getting back it "No Content"- My Ideal has both "Content" & "No Content" based on the output of my Python Script I'm running *ListUsersWith* - Correct, you can't see the relation to AWS & Boto3 as it\'s in my script I'm running *ListUsersWith*.  I'm trying to get an If statement for whether the script returns content or not and print based on that. Basically translate my Bash into Python.

Comment: I recommend that you simply write all the logic in Python. Given that you know Python, it will be simpler to do these things in Python than in shell scripts.

Comment: It was already written in Bash, but moving everything into Python, that's the part I'm stuck at, could you she'd any light?

Comment: Does the current answer help? If not, can you describe what you still need at this point?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the status of IAM users and credentials from the [AWS Credentials Report](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_getting-report.html). That would probably satisfy most needs.

If you prefer Python, then I've written a basic script that can be used to print out all IAM users in an account whose access keys are over 90 days old (regardless of when they last used these keys).

```
import sys
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

DAYS = 90

iam = boto3.client('iam')
sts = boto3.client('sts')

identity = sts.get_caller_identity()
account = identity['Account']
header_printed = False

count = 0
today = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

# Get all IAM users in this AWS account
for user in iam.list_users()['Users']:
    arn = user['Arn']
    username = user['UserName']

    # Get all access keys for this IAM user
    keys = iam.list_access_keys(UserName=username)

    # Test each key's age and print those that are too old
    for key in keys['AccessKeyMetadata']:
        akid = key['AccessKeyId']
        created = key['CreateDate']
        created_delta = today - created

        # if this access key is older than DAYS
        if created + timedelta(days=DAYS) < today:
            count += 1
            response = iam.get_access_key_last_used(AccessKeyId=akid)
            akid_last_used = response['AccessKeyLastUsed']

            if not header_printed:
                header_printed = True
                print(f'Account, Username, Access Key, Age, Last Used')

            print(f'{account}, {username}, {akid}, {created_delta.days} ', end = '')

            # Only keys that have actually been used will have last used date
            if 'LastUsedDate' in akid_last_used:
                last_used = akid_last_used['LastUsedDate']
                last_used_delta = today - last_used
                print(flast_used_delta.days)
            else:
                print('none')

sys.exit(count)
```

This will print out a list of access keys over 90 days, in a CSV format. For example:

```
Account, Username, Access Key, Age, Last Used
123456784321, james, AKIAJ7PL4POLWNEXAMPLE, 91, 1
123456784321, frank, AKIAL2CV9LKWEXAMPLE, 200, 100
123456784321, mary, AKIAYTWHD3BNMLEXAMPLE, 97, none
```

The `Age` is how many days old the access key is. The `Last Used` is how many days it has been since the credential was last used. Hope this proves to be helpful.

The script's exit code is the count of keys older than 90 days, so you can use this exit code in a shell script to decide what to do next. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 scripts_older_than_90days.py > oldkeys.csv
count=$?

if [ $count -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "All access keys good"
else
  echo "Count of old keys" $count
fi
```

Comment: This this is helpful, but I'm looking how to replicate my if statement in Python. I already have a script to check IAM users, but when I push it through to SNS, I'd like it to display a message saying "account up to date" when there are no users, and if there are users, to run the command (this logic i would like in python).  I'm running through a list of 30+ accounts with my script

Comment: You can count the number of old keys within the Python script and then the Python script itself can invoke SNS with the relevant text (account keys good or bad). No need to do any of this in bash. If you really want to do it in bash then have the Python script sys.exit() with a zero (good) or non-zero (bad) value and you can test $? in your shell script. Don't test based on the presence or absence of some arbitrary text.